# No animation when adding points to two serieses in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am adding a new different point to each of two serieses in a chart similar to [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update).
If I have only one series, it's animated but for two serieses, it's not animated anymore. The x axis labels scroll smoothly though. Is there a way to animate them or is this a limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two animations are tripping each other up.  Add each point without redrawing, then redraw the chart.

```
      series1.addPoint([x, y1], false, true); //false is to not redraw
      series2.addPoint([x, y2], false, true);
      chart.redraw();
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LdPs/).

EDIT:

You can also use

```
series1.addPoint([x, y1], false, true); //false is to not redraw
series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
```

and you don't need to chart.redraw();

Answer (score 0):

you can redraw the chart after a certain amount points have been added.

```
series1.addPoint([x, y1], false, true);
series2.addPoint([x, y2], false, true);
chart.redraw();
```