# No animation when adding data with series.addPoint()

Tags: highcharts

I've a chart with the animation option set to true. But when I use series.addPoint() function to add new data to my chart, the data is added, but there is no animation. I've the problem in all browsers. Are there any requirement for this feature to work which I don't know? I'am using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.0

Arr. I've found a solution: [No animation when adding points to two serieses in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240930/no-animation-when-adding-points-to-two-serieses-in-highcharts)

Thank you

Torben

Comment: post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Set animation paramter as true

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Comment: I've set the parameter animation 'true'. Same problem as before. The chart.animation property is set true too. I've some kind of animation, but it doesn't look like the one in the samples. The line is drawn without any animation and after that the markers move to the left. This movement is animated ...

Comment: Could you recreate your issue in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I've found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240930/no-animation-when-adding-points-to-two-serieses-in-highcharts

Comment: Indeed it looks like simialar.